# Laravel Array Values NULL on Model create method

Tags: laravel, model, eloquent

its very suspect. I have an array with values. But when I use a create method on the model the values are NULL.
When I use the update function all values are right.

```
protected function createProduct(array $data)
{
//        dd($data['category_id']);
    return Product::create([
        'category_id'     => $data['category_id'],
        'manufacturer_id' => $data['manufacturer_id'],
        'sku'             => $data['sku'],
        'collection'      => $data['collection'],
        'name'            => $data['name'],
        'name_en'         => $data['name_en'],
        'sku_supplier'    => $data['sku_supplier'],
        'order'           => $data['order'],
    ]);
```

//

Comment: What is the output when you dd($data); ?

Comment: What does the dd($data) return? Can you see all the data as intended?

Answer (score 2):

`create()` is using [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature so you need to add all values to the `$fillable` property first which should be added to `Product` model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['category_id', 'manufacturer_id', 'sku', 'collection', 'name', 'name_en', 'sku_supplier', 'order'];
```

Also, you can just do this to create new product:

```
return Product::create($data);
```

Comment: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `mnm_products` (`category_id`, `manufacturer_id`, `sku`, `collection`, `name`, `name_en`, `sku_supplier`, `einkauf`, `hek`, `vpe`, `kvk`, `stock`, `in_stock`, `visible`, `natalie`, `order`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 2017-01-05 17:39:18, 2017-01-05 17:39:18))"

Comment: Please post result of `dd($data)` and show `Product` model.

Comment: Query result really looks like mass assignment doesn't work, because there are timestamps in the query, but nothing else.

Comment: if you are fine with fields being mass-assigned you can do the following:     protected $guarded = [];